# Is the sentence 'That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique.' correct?

Tags: that

I encountered the sentence "That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique." It is from a text book. There is an audio file of it as well. Here is the script:

> **A**: What is it exactly?
>
> **B**: I have a picture of it. Here. [*He shows a picture of the thing he
>   thought he lost.*]
>
> **B**: It's uh... it's a teddy bear. Right. Ok, thank you officer.
>
> **A**: What did he say?
>
> **B**: That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique.
>
> **A**: Well, this is just awful! What could've happened?

My question is the following. Is "That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique"  a grammatical sentence?

Why are 'that' and 'a' put together?

Comment: A 20 year old teddy bear may be vintage; but an antique is at least 100 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I answer your question, we need to review the difference between *direct speech* and *indirect speech*.

Quotation marks are used for reports of [direct speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_speech), that is, reports which attribute specific words to someone. For example,

> **Tom**: Flies like honey.
>
> **Mike**: Tom said "Flies like honey." [**Direct speech**]

Quotation marks are *not* used for [indirect speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech). Further, using a 'that' is an optional way to introduce the clause that paraphrases what the person being quoted said. These are called [content clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause) or *that-clauses*. This use of 'that' is called the *complementizer*. Here is an example:

> **Tom**: Flies like honey.
>
> **Mike**: Tom said (that) flies like honey. [**Indirect speech**]

Notice that Mike is allowed to say 'that' here.

Now, on to your question:

"That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique" is *NOT* a grammatical sentence by itself.

When speaker A says "That a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique", he is *not* using a *full* sentence. Rather, he is using an *elliptical* sentence. His full sentence would be the indirect speech report: "**The officer said** that a teddy bear from 1996 is not an antique." Speaker A is just using the *content clause* from this sentence (see above). You're allowed to do this in conversation when the immediately preceding context makes it clear how to finish your sentence.

It's very similar to the following dialogue:

> **A**: Who broke the window?
>
> **B**: Maria.

Here, speaker B is *not* using a *full* sentence. But context makes it clear that she means something like "Maria broke the window". The same thing is happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But it's not about direct/indirect speech.

Comment: @Silenus I up-voted your answer, but your subsequent edit of the OP's question significantly changes its reading (and possibly intent). The 'script' would be better placed in your answer, I think.

Comment: @Jimin--I don't think Silenus said that it was about direct/indirect speech.   He (she?) was just giving background.  If you'd prefer, read from the paragraph that begins "When speaker A says..." and you'll find that your answer is in there, in the discussion of elliptical sentences.

Comment: @Lawrence OP provided the script, which provides the essential context and shows exactly what OP misunderstood; OP should have included it in the question to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments all. The OP did provide the script (as an answer), so I rather significantly edited the question to include it (after which the answer was deleted). Hopefully everything is cleared up now.

Comment: @StoneyB and Silenus, thanks for the clarification. Let's leave the trail of comments up, in case future visitors wonder about the same thing.

Comment: @Silenus Wow! Now I get what you meant!! THank you so much!! The original sentence was 'The officer said that a teddy bear....' I didn't notice that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

*That* serves a dual purpose in English: as a *demonstrative* pronoun that indicates a specific instance of the noun (*that* bear), and as a *relative* pronoun, which starts a dependent clause (*that* a bear . . .). In the latter instance, it can be followed by *a* or *the*; this is not possible in the former.